# Configure Apache Web server to use a proxy server

Tags: apache, proxy, webserver

I want to configure Apache web server to use a proxy server, so that all the outbound requests go through this proxy server. Could you please help me how to do this? I tried with Proxifier, but it didn't help me much.

Comment: you want it so that if a client requests a page (not from the proxy) the response goes through the proxy? or if an application / script on the server makes and outbound request for data it goes through the proxy?

Comment: Yes the second one - when the HTTP Server makes an outbound request, it should go through the proxy

Comment: what is making the outbound request from apache?  A script or are you using mod_proxy?

Comment: Yes I'm using a mod_proxy. There is a proxy pass rule created which forwards some url patterns to a different domain

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to proxy outbound requests, you can use ProxyRemote from mod_proxy http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote

`ProxyRemote * http://ip.of.proxY.host:port`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache the simpler way is to define a global variable http_proxy. On RedHat like edit /etc/sysconfig/httpd and adjust these two lines to your environment:

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy:8080/" 
export https_proxy="http://proxy:8080/"
```